Error when read json file from python package
I have the following Python package structure
MyPackage/
- assets/
 - __init__.py
 - asset.py
 - vulnerability_template.json
 - warn.json
- setup.py

I already included the JSON files in the package by defining it in the setup.py
The asset.py is the following code:
def get_json_asset(file_name: str) -> dict:
    try:
        with open(file_name) as f:
            return json.loads(f.read())
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

When I try to call get_json_asset from code in another package that depends on MyPackage, I get the error
No such file or directory: 'vulnerability_template.json'

According to your post, you have just file1.json, file2.json, no vulnerability_template.json. Update your question if it's not true.
Another option: try  assets/vulnerability_template.json, as I understood the project structure. Still it's very confusing, is setup.py in MyPackage or in assets? Or outside all of the directories?

Wht's the point of an exception handler which simply immediately raises the error?

When the computer tells you a file doesn’t exist, it’s nearly always right. A typical beginner mistake is supplying the wrong directory name. If you are a Windows user, dragging the file to a CMD window will reveal its correct path; similar mechanisms nre often available in other GUIs, too. Possible duplicate of What exactly is current working directory?

@MaksymAndreiev , I modified the structure to align with the error. The setup is in the package directory. As I mentioned, I already included the files, which are part of the package and exist.

Assuming that assets is a subfolder containing the JSON file, the file path can be created as follows:
file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "assets" / file_name

If the JSON file is in the same folder as the asset.py source file then there is no need to add the subfolder to the file path:
file_path = Path(__file__).parent / file_name

Complete code including pathlib import:
import json
from pathlib import Path

def get_json_asset(file_name: str) -> dict:
    file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "assets" / file_name
    try:
        with open(file_path) as f:
            return json.loads(f.read())
    except Exception as e:
        raise e


Will it work if I call get_json_asset from code in another package?

Path(__file__).parent is the path to the folder containing the file where get_json_asset() is defined.

I tried this code but I got the same error. I call the function from another package

Where is the json file relative to asset.py?

Same level. Both are in the assets directory

Then simply remove the "assets"  folder from file_path. Change the line to file_path = Path(__file__).parent / file_name.
